# Get Page_not_found on Django project

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I got page_not_found when try to use url:

```
from django.urls import path from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/posts/<int:post_id>/', views.get_post, name='get_post'), ]
```

To my view function in small Django project:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response


def get_post(post_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

Asking for help)

Comment: try api/v1/posts/<int:post_id>/ instead of api/v1/posts/int:post_id/. Note "<>"

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/) you should write:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/posts/<int:post_id>/', views.get_post, name='get_post'),
]
```

instead of:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/posts/int:post_id/', views.get_post, name='get_post'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I already write like you say. Have now idea why I copypaste it like this.

Comment: And in you browser, you are using url (or similar) localhost:8000/api/v1/posts/3/. And you have a post in your database with the id you're writing in the url?